# Parse.com: How to find localStore objects in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

On the parse documentation, there is only the objective-C version of the `PFQuery.findObjectsInBackground` method :

```
[[query findObjectsInBackground] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
  if (task.error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    return task;
  }

  NSLog(@"Retrieved %d", task.result.count);
  return task;
}];
```

I am new to Swift and I couldn't translate it. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Change the code on [the parse doc](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects/iOS) to Swift (in the code div, bottom right Corner)

An example would be:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects, error) in
    if error == nil {
        // do whatever you want with your objects (Array of AnyObject)
        // cast to Array of PFFile
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for swift 3.0 version.it working for me.

```
query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in

                if(error == nil)
                {
                    print("Data \(objects)");
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Error Data :\(error)");
                }

            })
```